# Get emailer to send FME log files to my email address once work bench has run

Tags: fme-form

I would like to receive and email with a log file in attached or in the body of the email when a workspace is run. I'm using FME Desktop. I thought about reading the logfile using a feature reader then an emailer to send it. however don't think there is a reader for .log files.

Any suggestions? I don't have FME server.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possible solutions, but I would use a WorkspaceRunner to run the original workspace and then send the log from that workspace with an emailer transformer.